# Pyinstaller PyQt5 ModuleNotFoundError Second Window Won't Open

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, specifications, modulenotfounderror

I am attempting to open a second GUI using PyQt5 and a second .py file - it works in the IDE but not when compiled as a single .exe. The first GUI opens, the second does not. I receive ModuleNotFoundError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\ProjectName\dist\firstwindow\secondwindow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I have tried modifying the spec file in so many ways now that I can't even recall. From what I can tell, Pyinstaller has no issues importing modules from the first .py file, but when it attempts a second level import or hidden import on the secondwindow.py - it has issues.

I've tried pointing to the sql module in the pathex, datas and hidden imports fields of the spec file. I am entering text such as `'C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectName\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\mysql'` into all three of these fields and still receiving the same error.

I have tried using --hiddenimport=mysql as in: `pyinstaller --onefile --hiddenimport=mysql test.spec`

In the example below, I have imported mysql.connector and arbitrarily used it in the code. This is to demonstrate the error I am receiving in my actual program relating to mysql. If I remove mysql.connector or attempt to import PyQt5 beforehand, I still have errors relating to PyQt5.

Minimum Reproducible Code:

firstwindow.py

```
import mysql.connector
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
import subprocess
import sys

db = mysql.connector.connect()

class FirstWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Push for Window")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

    def show_new_window(self, checked):
        subprocess.Popen("secondwindow.py", shell=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = FirstWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

secondwindow.py

```
import mysql.connector
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
import sys

db = mysql.connector.connect()


class NewWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Second Window Opened")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = NewWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

test.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['firstwindow.py', 'secondwindow.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectName', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectName\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\mysql'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('firstwindow.py', '.'), ('secondwindow.py', '.'), ('C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectName\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\mysql', '.')],
             hiddenimports=['C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectName\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\mysql'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='firstwindow',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='firstwindow')
```

followed by: `pyinstaller --onefile test.spec`

Comment: remove --onefile option

Comment: @eyllanesc Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue for me. I was originally not using --onefile, but similar questions advised to use it. I'm thinking the problem may be to do with the way in which I am opening a new window: `subprocess.Popen("secondwindow.py", shell=True)` . Do you have any thoughts on that?
Also I am not sure if it is relevant, but in my actual code I am using two external .ui files for my windows. However the problem persists in my minimum reproducible example with the same error.

Comment: Why do you use subprocess for a trivial task? Better change that code for `from secondwindow import NewWindow` and  `self.new_window = NewWindow()` `self.new_window.show()`

Comment: @eyllanesc This worked a charm. Thanks you so much, please answer so I can mark as correct.
As for your question of "Why am I using subprocess?"
Because I am new to PyQt and don't know what I'm doing

I did also just find another, far less elegant solution myself. In the spec file under datas, by adding the path: `'C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectName\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages`. Previously I was adding `C:\\Users\\Me\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectName\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\mysql`. Problem with this is that it added every site package to the dist folder increasing the size massively.